# flexislider display broken in ie

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, slider

The image is stacking on others in ie9. It works ok with FF and chorome.

Beside that, how to stop animation when it plays video?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the ie 9 don't support html5 ,you can try to add :

```
`<!--[if IE]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->`
```

in my ie 9 browser 's console,there is some wrong with jquery,it can't find jquery `$`

```
`SCRIPT5009: “jQuery” not defined 
  jquery.flexslider.js, line7 char 1
SCRIPT5007: property “$”'s value is null、not defined or not Function object 
  html.php, line9 char3`
```

Comment: thanks for comment. actually moving <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" > up to head resolved display problem. sorry but do you know how to stop animation when it plays video?